# Column operations on pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
     id   Category   Time
1    176       12      00:00:00
2    4956      2       00:00:00
3    583       4       00:00:04
4    9395      2       00:00:24
5    176       12      00:03:23
```

which is basically a set of `id` and the `category` of item they used at a particular `Time`. I use `df.groupby['id']` and then I want to see if they used the same category or different and assign True or False respectively (or `NaN` if that was the first item for that particular `id`. I also filtered out the data to remove all the `id`s with only one `Time`.

For example one of the groups may look like

```
      id   Category   Time
1    176       12      00:00:00
2    176       12      00:03:23
3    176       2       00:04:34
4    176       2       00:04:54
5    176       2       00:05:23
```

and I want to perform an operation to get

```
      id   Category   Time          Transition
1    176       12      00:00:00       NaN
2    176       12      00:03:23       False
3    176       2       00:04:34       True
4    176       2       00:04:54       False
5    176       2       00:05:23       False
```

I thought about doing an `apply` of some sorts to the `Category` column after `groupby` but I am having trouble figuring out the right function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need a `groupby` here, you just need `sort` and `shift`.

```
df.sort(['id', 'Time'], inplace=True)
df['Transition'] = df.Category != df.Category.shift(1)
df.loc[df.id != df.id.shift(1), 'Transition'] = np.nan
```

i haven't tested this, but it should do the trick